# How can I get a stack trace of a remote (that is, not within my process) thread?

Tags: c++, windows

Let's say I'm writing a debugger. How do I build a stack trace on Windows systems? I don't need to enumerate symbols and such; just the addresses of the various function calls on the stack. I already have a handle to the thread with VM_READ access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billy,

[DBGHELP.DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679292%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is your friend here.  All sorts of [useful functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679291%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for those who wish to perform debugger like activities...

In it you find goodies like [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and others that allow you to specify the target process to manipulate.  Of course, you'll likely need to ensure that your debugger process has SeDebugPrivilege granted upon itself.

Have fun!

Comment: It should be pointed out that you only need SeDebugPrivilege to debug/access another process which you would not normally have access to. If you are debugging your own processes you don't need to enable it.